# How to make my identity column consecutive on delta table in Azure Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, merge, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am trying to create a delta table with a consecutive identity column. The goal is for our clients  to see if there is some data they did not receive from us.

It looks like the generated identity column is not consecutive. Which makes the "INCREMENT BY 1" quite misleading.

```py
    store_visitor_type_name = ["apple","peach","banana","mango","ananas"]
    card_type_name = ["door","desk","light","coach","sink"]
    store_visitor_type_desc = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday"]
    colnames = ["column2","column3","column4"]
    data_frame = spark.createDataFrame(zip(store_visitor_type_name,card_type_name,store_visitor_type_desc),colnames)
    data_frame.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_increment')
    data_frame.display()
```

```sql
   
    
    CREATE or REPLACE TABLE TEST(
      `column1SK` BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1)
      ,`column2` STRING
      ,`column3` STRING
      ,`column4` STRING
      ,`inserted_timestamp` TIMESTAMP
      ,`modified_timestamp` TIMESTAMP
    )
    USING delta
    LOCATION '/mnt/Marketing/Sales';
    
    
    MERGE INTO TEST as target
    USING vw_increment as source
    ON target.`column2` = source.`column2`
    
    WHEN MATCHED 
    
    AND (target.`column3` <> source.`column3`
    OR target.`column4` <> source.`column4`)
    THEN
      UPDATE SET
        `column2` = source.`column2`
        ,`modified_timestamp` = current_timestamp() 
        
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (
        `column2`
        ,`column3`
        ,`column4`
        ,`modified_timestamp`
        ,`inserted_timestamp`
      ) VALUES (
        source.`column2`
        ,source.`column3`
        ,source.`column4`
        ,current_timestamp()
        ,current_timestamp()
      )
```

I'm getting the following results. You can see this is not sequential.What is also very confusing is that *it is not starting at 1*, w**hile explicitely mentionned in the query**.

I can see in the documentation (https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html#parameters) :

> The automatically assigned values start with start and increment by
> step. Assigned values are unique but are not guaranteed to be
> contiguous. Both parameters are optional, and the default value is 1.
> step cannot be 0.

Is there a workaround to make this identity column consecutive ?

I guess I could have another column and do a `ROW_NUMBER` operation after the `MERGE`, but it looks expensive.

[image]

Comment: If you need consecutive numbers for all the columns, then row_number() might be the way. Don't create `column1SK` in test. Use the same merge operation and then use the query as `select row_number() over(order by column2),* from test;` to get consecutive identity results.

Comment: As long as ascending should not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Pyspark to achieve the requirement instead of using `row_number()` function.

- I have read the `TEST` table as a spark dataframe and converted it to pandas on spark dataframe. In pandas dataframe, using `reset_index()`, I have created a new index column.
- Then I have converted it back to spark dataframe. I have added 1 to the index column values since the index starts with 0.

```
df = spark.sql("select * from test")
pdf = df.to_pandas_on_spark()

#to create new index column.
pdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
final_df = pdf.to_spark()

#Since index starts from 0, I have added 1 to it.
final_df.withColumn('index',final_df['index']+1).show()
```

[image]